# How can I encrypt data in a LAN or Interanet while transmitting?

Tags: encryption, lan, transmission

I want to encrypt the data in a LAN or internet while transmitting. Is it possible?

If yes, how? Can I use IPsec for this, or is there any other protocol to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to encrypt the data in a LAN or internet while transmitting. Is it possible?

There are several option (TLS/SSL or IPSec may be the most common). Maybe you should specify your use case to get any better answer.

Basic indutrial protocol today used for encrypting network traffic is [SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). Imho this is your best and simplest option. Almost every platform or programming language already contain libraries for implementing TLS.

> If yes, how? Can I use IPsec for this, or is there any other protocol to do this?

I'd really got for TLS/SSL as operating on higher network layer than IPSec.